# How I pass argument as index to jq?

Tags: json, parsing, jq

Hi I would like to access a given element in the json array as below:

```
$ echo '[  { "CT" : "OS1"  , "VERSION" : "3" } , { "CT" : "OS2"  , "VERSION" : "3" } ]'  | jq '.[1]'
{
  "CT": "OS2",
  "VERSION": "3"
}
```

However I would like to use a variable (from the environment in the future) replacing the index '1' in the command above but this produces an error.

```
echo '[  { "CT" : "OS1"  , "VERSION" : "3" } , { "CT" : "OS2"  , "VERSION" : "3" } ]'  | jq --arg index 1 '.[$index]'
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index array with string "1"
```

It looks like it cannot parse this 1 as a numerical value once resolved like this. Is somebody able to help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `--argjson` option:

```
jq --argjson index 1 '.[$index]'
```

As mentioned in the `jq --help`:

> `--argjson a v`  set variable `$a` to JSON **value** `<v>`;

Comment: Can someone explain why using arg vs argjson here doesn't work e.g. `jq --arg index 1 '.[$index]'`. I spent a couple hours trying to get this to work with arg and your answered solved this for me.

Comment: @Dude0001 `--arg` sets the variable as a _string_, whereas `--argjson` sets the variable as a json value and, in this case, as a number that can be used as an index array.

Answer (score 2):

If you have jq 1.4 or older, you could use the [`tonumber`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#tonumber) function:

```
jq --arg index 1 '.[$index | tonumber]'
```

For more recent versions, refer to [oliv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52609445/3266847).